# how to make a thread to sleep in Mule4?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, mulesoft, mule-esb

I'm trying a scenario, where mule has to repost a message to an endpoint for certain error case.
eg: server down-503,502..
I couldn't use **untilsuccefull** processor, since there is no option to set for which error codes it has to repost.
So im trying a simple flow logic to handle this.
Under onErrorcontinue, im setting a counter and try to repost same message.
Where i need to make the thread to sleep for a minute.
How can I do that in Mule4? I dont see any sleep processor.

Im following this guide
https://www.tutorialsatoz.com/retry-mechanism-until-success-vs-flow-reference/

Answer (score 1):

The technique presented in the article uses two **bad practices**:

1. Using sleep() in Mule 4
2. Using a recursive flow ref

You can use sleep(), in a Groovy script as the article, or using DataWeave's wait() function as suggested in @Alex response, is a really bad idea in Mule 4. The reason is that those methods use CPU Intensive threads that are a very limited resource in Mule 4. The documentation for [wait()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-runtime-functions-wait) clearly spells that it can cause issues, and its intention is only to be used for testing purposes, and should not be used in a production application:

> Stopping the execution will block the thread used, potentially causing
> slowness, low performance and potentially freezes of the entire
> runtime. This operation is intented for limited functional testing
> purposes and should not be used in production application, performance
> testing or with multiple applications deployed.

You can mitigate this issue a bit by creating your own sleep module with Mule SDK and ensuring that the operation is forced to use the BLOCKING thread pool.

Another alternative is to use Mule 4.3 which uses a single thread pool for all kinds of executions.

Using a recursive flow reference can cause an unrecoverable stack overflow error and it is not recommended nor intended to be done in Mule 4.

Instead of this method, you might try to use [`<raise-error>`](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/raise-error-component-reference) inside an `<until-successful>` to raise a custom error if the conditions required are not met.

Comment: @ aled , Im using Mule 4.3 runtime. so how the backend implementation done in UnitilSuccesfull processor? Is it not a wait and repost mechanism? Actually I like to use Unitillsuccesfull, but it will try for all error senarios. But I dont want to do it. Only for server down, connection errors I want to repost the message . I dont want to degrade the server performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wait function inside DW script but I would not recommend it - whole runtime will be waiting.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::Runtime
output application/json
---
{
    a: now()
} wait 4000 // wait 4 seconds
```

Comment: As Alex says, using wait(), or sleep() in Java/Groovy can impact your whole runtime and cause performance issues and even outages.

Comment: @alex, so how the backend implementation done in UnitilSuccesfull processor? Is it not a wait and repost mechanism? Actually I like to use Unitillsuccesfull, but it will try for all error senarios. But I dont want to do it. Only for server down, connection errors I want to repost the message

Comment: Im using Mule 4.3 runtime. I dont want to degrade the server performance. It is an exponential backoff retry mechanism im trying in mule4.3